# SQL query with multiple conditions in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have been trying to fetch records based on 'category' (should be Where clause) with few other constraints as below. Please guide me on where to insert the where clause in my code below as where category=$category.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('proj_item_details','proj_item_images');
$this->db->join('proj_item_images', 'proj_item_images.proj_id=proj_item_details.proj_id');
$this->db->like('proj_item_title',$params['search']['keywords']);
$this->db->order_by('proj_item_title',$params['search']['sortBy']);
$this->db->limit($params['limit'],$params['start']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this.

1.No need to define two tables at `from` statement.

2.Place your where condition after `joining` two tables.

3.In `order_by` and `like` statements define your `table` properly.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('proj_item_details');//only one table name here
$this->db->join('proj_item_images', 'proj_item_details.proj_id=proj_item_images.proj_id');
$this->db->where('proj_item_details.category', $category);//where condition here

$this->db->like('proj_item_details.proj_item_title',$params['search']['keywords']);//define table_name.column_name
$this->db->order_by('proj_item_details.proj_item_title',$params['search']['sortBy']);//define table_name.column_name
$this->db->limit($params['limit'],$params['start']);
```

Comment: Glad to help you.Best of luck ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line into your code-

```
$this->db->where('proj_item_details.category', $category);
```

**Example-**

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('proj_item_details','proj_item_images');
$this->db->where('proj_item_details.category', $category);
$this->db->join('proj_item_images', 'proj_item_images.proj_id=proj_item_details.proj_id');
$this->db->like('proj_item_title',$params['search']['keywords']);
$this->db->order_by('proj_item_title',$params['search']['sortBy']);
$this->db->limit($params['limit'],$params['start']);
```

Comment: Sure man..proj_item_details.category isn't necessary in my case although it is a good practice to avoid confusion when having multiple table that might have same field names. Thanks a lot